# Возможно ли boolean перевести в int

Tags: java

Возможно ли boolean перевести в int для сортировки с помощью Comparable.

```
true = 1
false = -1
```

Comment: Почти во всех языках false - это 0.

Comment: Java строго типизированный язык. `boolean` может быть только `true` или `false`.

Comment: для сортировки чего? массива типа boolean[]?

Answer (score 6):

Может быть

```
boolean b = true;    
int i = b ? 1 : -1
```

Comment: Дурацкие скобки, а то бы плюс поставил...

Comment: В спецификациях if (expr) пишут. Привычка :)

Comment: Вредная привычка, там приоритет другой.

Answer (score 5):

Не совсем понятно зачем, но можно так

```
boolean a = false;
int i = a ? 1 : -1;
```

Если нужно отсортировать массив Boolean, можно сделать так:

```
Boolean[] bools = new Boolean[]{true, false, true, false};
        Arrays.sort(bools, new Comparator<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Boolean o1, Boolean o2) {
                if (o1 && !o2)
                    return 1;
                else if (!o1 && o2)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        });
```

или с лямбдой:

```
Arrays.sort(bools, (o1, o2) -> {
            if (o1 && !o2)
                return 1;
            else if (!o1 && o2)
                return -1;
            else
                return 0;
        });
```

Comment: `o1?(o2?0:1):(o2?-1:0)`

Answer (score 2):

Отсортировать массив можно довольно просто:

```
Arrays.sort(bools, (x, y) -> x == y ? 0 : x ? 1 : -1);
```

Но если в массиве действительно лежат booleaan'ы (т. е. это не поле какого-то объекта), то сортировать его не надо, достаточно просто посчитать количество.

Answer (score 2):

Класс `Boolean` уже реализует `Comparable<Boolean>`, так что при сортировке дополнительные действия не требуются.

```java
Boolean[] arr = new Boolean[] {true, false, true, false};
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Если нужно сортировать по булевому полю класса, сложности также не возникнут.

```java
public class Record {
    private final boolean flag;

    public boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }

    ...
}
```

```java
Record[] arr = new Record[] {new Record(true), new Record(false)};
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(Record::getFlag));
```

В конце концов, для сравнения примитивных `boolean` есть [Boolean::compare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#compare(boolean,%20boolean))

```java
System.out.println(Boolean.compare(false, true)); // -1
```